# Find neo4j nodes with more than one incoming relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find all the nodes with more than one incoming relationship.  Given this data:

```
a-[has]->b
a-[has]->c
d-[has]->b
```

So, I'm looking for a query that returns 'b', because it has more that one incoming.

This query is close. It returns 'a' and 'b', because they both have 2 relations:

```
match (n)--()
with n,count(*) as rel_cnt
where rel_cnt > 1
return n;
```

However, this query (the addition of '-->') doesn't return any and I don't know why:

```
match (n)-->()
with n,count(*) as rel_cnt
where rel_cnt > 1
return n;
```

Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH ()-[r:has]->(n)
WITH n, count(r) as rel_cnt
WHERE rel_cnt > 1
RETURN n;
```

I am assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that 'has' is the appropriate relationship type. If not, then try:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->(n)
WITH n, count(r) as rel_cnt
WHERE rel_cnt > 1
RETURN n;
```

Comment: Thanks, both your queries work and my original.  It turns out I wasn't creating the nodes correctly and I had 2 nodes named a.  A newbie mistake I suppose.